# Is "would" correct in the answer "I would not agree on this matter"?

Tags: modal-verbs, spoken-english

If I want to  answer this question:

> Would you agree that subjects like science and maths are more difficult than art and literature?

Can I say *"I would not agree on this matter"*? Why or why not?

Comment: Yes, you can use "would" and that is probably the most common response. If you feel more strongly, you might just say, "I do not agree...."

Comment: Meanwhile, I would say, "No, I would not agree with this statement." I would not say, "on this matter." Is this for an essay you're writing?

Comment: No, It is For speaking ... so I could say in my answer  ,  No , I would not agree with this matter ..yes?  But I heard  from a movie that 2 people were talking with each other and one of them said "I  agree on the matter" so why they said on the matter ?

Comment: Why haggle over the word 'matter' or 'statement'? You can say, quite simply, "No, I don't agree", or "No. I don't agree with this." The context, where you are making an immediate response to a question, means that it is completely unambiguous that you are answering the question just asked! In the film, the person might have meant "I agree on the matter -- but I disagree with the intent" -- in other words, he agrees with the proposition, but disagrees with the reason the subject was raised in the first place -- maybe it was to forward a political policy he objected to!

Comment: @Maryprincess55321 Do you know what the two people were talking about?

Comment: I rememeber they talking about a particular matter .. but I dont know what was  ecaxctly  .. I heard from friends series

Answer (score 3):

"Would" is conditional.  It can serve several purposes.

As an actual conditional, there would be a condition.  "Would you agree...**if**...?"  Your response could be a simple yes or no since the conditions have already been stipulated.

Similarly, if the question is "Do you agree...?", you could respond with a simple yes or no if the answer is that straightforward.  If your answer is conditional, you could respond, "I would, if ..."

"Do you agree..." frames the question as a binary choice.  "Would" can use its conditional nature to simply soften the question or ask it in a polite way.  In that case, there is not an explicit condition, it is more a matter of affording some wiggle room in the answer by recognizing the possibility of conditions.

In this case, the response to "Would you agree..." could be yes or no, but it could also be the parallel construction "I would" or "I would not", without stating explicit conditions.  That response would be ambiguous as to whether you actually mean yes/no, or the answer depends on conditions.  You could also include explicit conditions.

Answer (score 2):

"Would" is conditional.  When an English speaker says, "I would not agree", he is implying something along the lines of "I would not agree... if you asked me... which you didn't... because it's none of my business... but if you did ask... which you didn't... I would then disagree... politely."

In other words, it's a way to say "I disagree" while tacitly acknowledging that it is not the speaker's decision.

Answer (score 1):

## To answer your first question simply:

> Can I say "*I would not agree on this matter.*"?

As @TeacherKSHuang states, ***yes***.

## As to your other question:

> Why or why not?

*Why* would you use the word ***would***? If you want to use more of a passive voice, you *would* make use of ***would***. Otherwise, you ***wouldn't***. Allow me to explain by way of example.

Take the following:

> No.

This sentence answers the question posed without qualification or reservation. This is firmly written in the "Active Voice"

> (No,) I would not (agree).

Now you're qualifying that *you* wouldn't think so, but you are qualifying that the answer only applies to you. We're moving into the passive voice now.

> (No,) I would not agree on this matter.

At this point, we're now qualifying both that the answer only applies to you, but also that the answer is particular to the details of the question. Not only are we using the passive voice, but we're also further qualifying the already softened answer.

Comment: Just so you know, "would" is conditional, not passive voice.